# Bash script for copying text currently entered to prompt

Tags: bash, terminal, bash-script

I'm trying to minimize using of mouse. Copying text in terminal is the mostly inconvenient activity for mouse avoiding. Now, `tmux` helping me to obtain this purpose. However, I regularly needs to copy text currently entered to bash prompt. *Currently entered text* means that I typed some symbols in prompt, but didn't press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `tmux` way for this purpose needs for too much keyboard shortcuts.

I'd like some script, that copying current text from prompt to clipboard. I want to add this script to `~/.bashrc` and assign keyboard shortcut to. How to write this script?

Comment: → http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994563/integrate-readlines-kill-ring-and-the-x11-clipboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
copy_buffer() {
  printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xclip -sel clipboard
}
bind -x '"\C-[c": "copy_buffer"'
```

Would store the current buffer to the clipboard selection upon pressing <kbd>Alt-C</kbd>.

Also note that `bash` (like all shells), has support for copy-paste inside the prompt. For instance <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> would kill the full buffer and paste (yank) it, leaving it in the yank buffer for you to yank it again later on would you want to.

See `zsh` or `tcsh` for more advanced features.

Comment: +1 especially for the hint for the bash internal shortcuts.